# icon not showing on navigation bar using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show an icon (arrow down) next to an item of the navigation bar using this line

```
background: url(ic_keyboard_arrow_down_white_18dp_1x.png) right
```

but nothing shows up. THis is the code. Any help appreciated.

```
ul {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0; auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 9px 18px 9px 18px;
  background: grey;
  margin-left: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}

li:hover a {
  background: grey;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

ul > li.sub{
    background: url(ic_keyboard_arrow_down_white_18dp_1x.png) right center no-repeat;
}

</style>

<ul id="menu">
  <li class="sub">
  <a href="#">Help</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">test1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">test3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this issue, and if you get rid of the gray background on the `<a>` tag, I mean on this style definition you wrote:

```
ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 9px 18px 9px 18px;
```

> background: grey;

```
  margin-left: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

you will see the icon.

if you want a background color, try defining the style on the `<li>` tag where the icon is, insted...and use a transparent background in order to blend the icon with the background color.

EXAMPLE (STYLE CSS):

```
<style>
    ul {
        font-family: Arial, Verdana;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: gray;
    }

        ul li {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
        }

    li ul {
        display: none;
    }

    ul li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
        padding: 9px 18px 9px 18px;
        margin-left: 1px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    ul li ul li a:hover, #menu:hover {
        background: #ddd;
    }

    li:hover ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }

    li:hover li {
        float: none;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    ul > li.sub {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_arrow_drop_down_48px-128.png) right center no-repeat;
        background-size: 24px;
    }
</style>
```

hope this was helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed the line and saw the arrow. But i dont know how to use a white colour and a transparent background at the same time at <li> tag

Comment: I meant that the picture background should be transparent,

Comment: hmmm i need to be solid white and use the arrow is this possible somehow?

Comment: so that when you set the background color on the <li> tag (the same <li> tag you set the background image to) then it will look better. I can't see what icon you are using so maybe it is already transparent, I suggested it just in case :) .

Comment: Thanks a lot this code works ok now. 

ul > li.sub{
    background: url(ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp_1x.png) right center no-repeat;
background-color: white;
}

Comment: happy to hear! I added an example style of what I did ( with a random icon from google that has transparent background )

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to use font awesome 
add this line in your `<head>` tag

```
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">



<ul id="menu">
  <li class="sub">
  <a href="#">Help <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">test1 <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">test3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

https://fontawesome.com